# Call to a member function when() on integer on laravel update query builder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

When the 'when' method is only one , the code can work fine.
But when I use continuous like below I got the error message

> Call to a member function when() on integer

I cannot figure what's the error? Any help is apprecited!

```
$variable=1;

    DB::table('products')
    ->where('id',$p_id)
    ->when($status_0_prop=='true', function($query) use ($variable){

            return $query->update(['status'=>$variable]);
    })
    ->when($queue_number_1_prop=='true', function($query) use ($variable){

            return $query->update(['queue_confirm_1'=>$variable]);
    })
    ->when($queue_number_2_prop=='true', function($query) use ($variable){

            return $query->update(['queue_confirm_2'=>$variable]);
    })
    ->when($queue_number_3_prop=='true', function($query) use ($variable){

            return $query->update(['queue_confirm_3'=>$variable]);
    })
    ->when($img_buy_prop=='true', function($query) use ($variable){

            return $query->update(['img_buy'=>$variable]);
    });
```

or how can I use the Eloquent to eloquent the method?

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `->get();` at the end.

```
$variable=1;

DB::table('products')
->where('id',$p_id)
->when($status_0_prop=='true', function($query) use ($variable){

        return $query->update(['status'=>$variable]);
})
->when($queue_number_1_prop=='true', function($query) use ($variable){

        return $query->update(['queue_confirm_1'=>$variable]);
})
->when($queue_number_2_prop=='true', function($query) use ($variable){

        return $query->update(['queue_confirm_2'=>$variable]);
})
->when($queue_number_3_prop=='true', function($query) use ($variable){

        return $query->update(['queue_confirm_3'=>$variable]);
})
->when($img_buy_prop=='true', function($query) use ($variable){

        return $query->update(['img_buy'=>$variable]);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `update` method returns an integer, I guess that your `$query`'s value get updated and is not a `Query\Builder` instance anymore.